# How to bind data to multiple areas from the same view model and the same observable array?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have data in an observable array which I am using to bind to `select option`.

*Data Source:*

```
        self.Artist = ko.observableArray([{
            "ArtistId": "1",
            "LastName": "Hunter",
            "FirstName": "Alfonzo",
            "Category": "Vocalist",
            "Genre": "Rythm and Blues",
            "DOB": "1/1/1973"
        },
        {
            "ArtistId": "2",
            "LastName": "Brown",
            "FirstName": "Horace",
            "Category": "Vocalist",
            "Genre": "Rythm and Blues",
            "DOB": "1/1/1981",
        },
        {
            "ArtistId": "2",
            "LastName": "Erik",
            "FirstName": "Sermon",
            "Category": "Rapper and Record Producer",
            "Genre": "HipHop",
            "DOB": "1/1/1977"
        },
        {
            "ArtistId": "3",
            "LastName": "Savage",
            "FirstName": "Chantay",
            "Category": "Vocalist",
            "Genre": "Rythm and Blues",
            "DOB": "1/1/1982"
        }]);
```

*Select Option:*

```
<select data-bind="options: artists,
                   optionsText: 'FullName',
                   value: selectedArtist"></select>
```

*Computed Observable:*

```
    self.artists = ko.computed(function () {
        return ko.utils.arrayMap(Artist(),

            function (data) {

                return {
                    FullName: data.FirstName + ' ' + data.LastName, value: data.ArtistId
                }
            });
    });
```

This works as needed but, I also need to bind the rest of the data to a `ul` or `paragraph` when an artist is selected  from the `select option`: E.g. Genre, Category and so on.

I need to use the same observable array and ***if possible*** the same computed observable: Not sure how that will work.

For example lets say the user selects: `Alphonzo Hunter` from the `select option`, then the following data is bind to a ul or another part of the page:

```
"LastName": "Hunter",
"FirstName": "Alfonzo",
"Category": "Vocalist",
"Genre": "Rythm and Blues",
"DOB": "1/1/1973"
```

Here is a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/185cbqp1/) without the additional bindings:

The only way I know how to do this is by creating multiple data sources and than passing the selected value as argument to another computed observable for the additional binding.

If I attempt something like this, it does not work: `LastName is undefined`:

```
        self.artistDeatail = ko.computed(function () {
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(Artist(), function (item) {
                return item.ArtistId === self.selectedArtist().value;
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `self.artists` observable array contains elements with two properties only - `FullName` and `value`. As a quick fix to keep all the properties of your initial `Artist` data and add some new props like `FullName` I suggest you to pass the initial data through a constructor function and then fill the observable array with these new objects.

This way you will have access to all properties of the selected artist and can use them in any element on your page - there is no limit on number of elements you can bind to your viewmodel.

Check demo: [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/185cbqp1/1/)

Comment: Thanks my friend: This works!! And also if the data is JSON, I simply put the loop into the callback. Thanks again!